# How to tell XmlSerializer to serialize properties with [DefautValue(...)] always?

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-serialization, default-value

I am using `DefaultValue` attribute for the proper `PropertyGrid` behavior (it shows values different from default in bold). Now if I want to serialize shown object with the use of `XmlSerializer` there will be no entries in xml-file for properties with default values.

**What is the easiest way to tell XmlSerializer to serialize these still?**

I need that to support "versions", so when I change default value later in the code - serialized property gets value it had serialized with, not "latest" one. I can think about following:

- Override behavior of `PropertyGrid` (use custom attribute, so it will be ignoreed by `XmlSerializer`);
- Do sort of a custom xml-serialization, where ignore `DefaultValue`'s;
- Do something with object before passing it to `XmlSeriazer` so it won't contain `DefaultValue`'s anymore.

But there is a chance I miss some secret property what allows to do it without much pain =D.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
    private bool _allowNegative = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set if negative results are allowed
    /// </summary>
    [Category(CategoryAnalyse)]
    [Admin]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ConverterBoolOnOff))]
    //[DefaultValue(false)] *1
    public bool AllowNegative
    {
        get { return _allowNegative; }
        set
        {
            _allowNegative = value;
            ConfigBase.OnConfigChanged();
        }
    }
    //public void ResetAllowNegative() { _allowNegative = false; } *2
    //public bool ShouldSerializeAllowNegative() { return _allowNegative; } *3
    //public bool ShouldSerializeAllowNegative() { return true; } *4
```

If I uncomment (*1), then I have desired effect in `PropertyGrid` - properties with default values are displayed in normal text, otherwise text is bold. However `XmlSerializer` will **NOT** put properties with default value into xml-file and this is **BAD** (and I am trying to fix it).

If I uncomment (*2) and (*3), then it's totally same as uncommenting (*1).

If I uncomment (*2) and (*4), then `XmlSerializer` will always put properties into xml-file, but this happens because they **do not have default value anymore** and `PropertyGrid` shows all values in bold text.

Comment: I would also suspect that even if you set a property explicitly to be the default value, the XMLSerializer would still NOT serialize the data because the value matches the default value.  Meaning I think your solution will be more of a custom serializer.

Comment: @BradRem was also thinking what this should be the right way to do it. It's just pity what same attribute is used for different purposes (threated differently) without thinking ahead. I would rather write `[XmlDefaultValue(...)]` and `[PropertyGridDefaultValue(...)]`. Dispite it is boring to write more attributes the end user then can select what exactly he needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you don't need attributes in your Xml, if you use the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) instead you will get the behavior you desire.

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowNegative { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Test));

    using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb2))
    {
        dcs.WriteObject(writer, new Test());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb2.ToString());  
}
```

produces (minus namespaces etc)

```
<Test>
    <AllowNegative>false</AllowNegative>
</Test>
```

Comment: Looks as very elegant and smart solution (you are not using `XmlSerialization` anymore, but produce something what looks like it). My the only question is if `XmlSerialization` can deserialize `DataContractSerializer` output back without problems. Have to also think about `Xml...` attributes (which I don't use atm), like `XmlElement`...

Comment: @Sinatr: Is there a reason you can't deserialize with DataContractSerializer?

Comment: Lol, didn't think about this as well =D Trying to test it atm.

Comment: Ok, after some tries, it works in principle, even better - if you don't add `[DataContract]` to the class, then all public properties will get serialized.. including those without setters =D I faces several issues: 1) properties get sorted, can I disable sorting (I'd like to have properties appears in the same order as they are defined in the class) 2) it's single line xml, is there an easy way to split it into lines (excluding posprocessing)? Also my issue will be to read data serialized already with `XmlSerializer`, but I think for this I can simply try to deserialize as contract...

Comment: .. and if it doesn't works - then use `XmlSerializer` (for backward compartibility). Serialization will always occurs with the contract. So only critical is how to add indents atm.

Comment: @sinatr: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx on how to order data members.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx on how to control formatting etc.

Comment: After some thoughts I came to the point what it is too risky to switch to `DataContractSerializer`. I may need to control serialization and it looks like `XmlSerializer` provides more options and initially is *better tuned* for the purpose of output customization.

Comment: Still, this answer is the best in a way, what there is a "centralized" place where you apply change, instead of changing something for every property.

Answer (score 4):

You could use two properties:

```
// For property grid only:
[Category(CategoryAnalyse)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ConverterBoolOnOff))]
[DefaultValue(false)]
[XmlIgnore]
public bool AllowNegative
{
    get { return _allowNegative; }
    set
    {
        _allowNegative = value;
        ConfigBase.OnConfigChanged();
    }
}

// For serialization:
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ConverterBoolOnOff))]
[XmlElement("AllowNegative")]
public bool AllowNegative_XML
{
    get { return _allowNegative; }
    set
    {
        _allowNegative = value;
        ConfigBase.OnConfigChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using similair idea when need to serialize arrays (to convert them into a compact string first). The problem is (if I decide to go this way for every property) what there will be **a lot** of repeatable properties when you are accessing class from outside (by using `InteliSense` ofc) and a not so small bit of work.

Comment: @Sinatr: You can use `EditorBrowsableAttribute` to hide the duplicate properties in IntelliSense.

Comment: `In Visual C#, EditorBrowsableAttribute does not suppress members from a class in the same assembly.`

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is [`ShouldSerialize()` and `Reset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx). Using these will expand your class a bit more (with two functions per property), however, it achieves specifically what you are looking for.

Here's a quick example:

```
// your property variable
private const String MyPropertyDefault = "MyValue";
private String _MyProperty = MyPropertyDefault;

// your property
// [DefaultValueAttribute("MyValue")] - cannot use DefaultValue AND ShouldSerialize()/Reset()
public String MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProperty; }
    set { _MyProperty = value; }
}


// IMPORTANT!
// notice that the function name is "ShouldSerialize..." followed
// by the exact (!) same name as your property
public Boolean ShouldSerializeMyProperty()
{
    // here you would normally do your own comparison and return true/false
    // based on whether the property should be serialized, however,
    // in your case, you want to always return true when serializing!

    // IMPORTANT CONDITIONAL STATEMENT!
    if (!DesignMode)
        return true; // always return true outside of design mode (is used for serializing only)
    else
        return _MyProperty != MyPropertyDefault; // during design mode, we actually compare against the default value
}

public void ResetMyProperty()
{
    _MyProperty = MyPropertyDefault;
}
```

Note that because you want to keep the PropertyGrid functionality in tact, you must *know* whether you are serializing or not when the `ShouldSerialize()` function is called. I suggest you implement some sort of control flag that gets set when serializing, and thus **always `return true`**.

---

Please note that you **cannot** use the `DefaultValue` attribute in conjunction with the `ShouldSerialize()` and `Reset()` functions (*you only use either or*).

---

**Edit:** Adding clarification for the `ShouldSerialize()` function.

Because there is currently **no** way to serialize a default value and let the PropertyGrid know that a property has its default value, you must implement a condition checking whether you are in design mode.

Assuming your class derives from a `Component` or `Control`, you have a `DesignMode` property which is set by Visual Studio at design time *only*. The condition looks as follows:

```
if (!DesignMode)
    return true; // always return true outside of design mode (is used for serializing only)
else
    return _MyProperty != MyPropertyDefault; // during design mode, we actually compare against the default value
```

---

**Edit 2:** We're not talking about Visual Studio's design mode.

With the above code in mind, create another property called `IsSerializing`. Set the `IsSerializing` property to `true` **before** calling `XmlSerializer.Serialize`, and unset it *after*.

Finally, change the `if (!DesignMode)` conditional statement to be `if (IsSerializing)`.

Comment: The documentation you link to says "Either apply the DefaultValueAttribute or provide ResetPropertyName and ShouldSerializePropertyName methods. Do not use both." If this is a valid exception to the rule (I do not know), you should probably provide a bit more info about why the rule does not apply here.

Comment: @hvd Thanks! I've updated my answer. I clearly had the incorrect understanding from that note.

Comment: Thanks, this is something interesting and nice to know. I also appreciate effort you put into describing it so clearly. But there is still a problem: both PropertyGrid and XmlSerializer are using either `DefaultValue` or `ShouldSerialize../Reset..` to determine default value and **I want PropertyGrid to show normal, not bold text, when value of property is default** this is nice for the user to quickly see out of dozens of options which were changed, however **I want at same time for XmlSerializer always serialize all properties, even if they have default value**. And this solution doesnt help

Comment: added explanation into question text

Comment: @Sinatr The comments in the code clearly stated that you **must use a control variable**, which gets set before serializing. I've edited my answer to use a better and more robust method (using [`ComponentModel.DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx)), along with better explanation.

Comment: @Jesse, then you misunderstood me, I am not talking about `Designer time`, but about `PropertyGrid` component, so in my case I am never in `DesignMode`. Actually now you gave me very good idea of how to do it with this the help of that **control variable** which I can set **just before serializing**. Which in theory should works. Give me a minute to check it.

Comment: @Sinatr definitely my mistake - I thought that by PropertyGrid you were referring to Visual Studio's design mode. I've updated my answer once more.

Comment: @Jesse, it works. Was thinking to add your answer to my question, but you have already done all the job! Btw, you can use `private` modifier to hide dozens of `ShouldSerialize../Reset..` from class users. What I like is what it works, what I dislike is an amount of work I have to do now (i have over 20 configuration classes, each consists of 30-50 properties) :-(

Comment: @Sinatr Great, glad it helped! Unfortunately, it sounds like you may have a lot of work ahead of you =\. Remember to mark this as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: @Jesse, might do, but `Phil`'s solution looks more appealing (adding only attributes is easier), would give credits to one which suit me the best at the end, because you can't split bounty or accept more than one answer :-(

Comment: @Sinatr that's how the site works. I was mentioning it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of the `XmlSerializer` can can be overwritten with 
[XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx)

I borrowed the idea from [here](http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/343227-force-default-values-serialization.html):

```
static public XmlAttributeOverrides GetDefaultValuesOverrides(Type type)
{
    XmlAttributeOverrides explicitOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    PropertyDescriptorCollection c = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type);
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in c)
    {
        AttributeCollection attributes = p.Attributes;
        DefaultValueAttribute defaultValue = (DefaultValueAttribute)attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)];
        XmlIgnoreAttribute noXML = (XmlIgnoreAttribute)attributes[typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute)];
        XmlAttributeAttribute attribute = (XmlAttributeAttribute)attributes[typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute)];

        if ( defaultValue != null && noXML == null )
        {
            XmlAttributeAttribute xmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute(attribute.AttributeName);
            XmlAttributes xmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
            xmlAttributes.XmlAttribute = xmlAttribute;
            explicitOverrides.Add(userType, attribute.AttributeName, xmlAttributes);
        }
    }
    return explicitOverrides;
}
```

And made my self an an Attribute to decorate the classes which should emit the default values. 
If you want do this for all classes, I'm sure you can adapt the whole concept.

```
Public Class EmitDefaultValuesAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
    Private Shared mCache As New Dictionary(Of Assembly, XmlAttributeOverrides)

    Public Shared Function GetOverrides(assembly As Assembly) As XmlAttributeOverrides
        If mCache.ContainsKey(assembly) Then Return mCache(assembly)
        Dim xmlOverrides As New XmlAttributeOverrides
        For Each t In assembly.GetTypes()
            If t.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(EmitDefaultValuesAttribute), True).Count > 0 Then
                AddOverride(t, xmlOverrides)
            End If
        Next
        mCache.Add(assembly, xmlOverrides)
        Return xmlOverrides
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub AddOverride(t As Type, xmlOverrides As XmlAttributeOverrides)
        For Each prop In t.GetProperties()
            Dim defaultAttr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DefaultValueAttribute), True).FirstOrDefault()
            Dim xmlAttr As XmlAttributeAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(XmlAttributeAttribute), True).FirstOrDefault()
            If defaultAttr IsNot Nothing AndAlso xmlAttr IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim attrs As New XmlAttributes '= {New XmlAttributeAttribute}
                attrs.XmlAttribute = xmlAttr
                ''overide.Add(t, xmlAttr.AttributeName, attrs)
                xmlOverrides.Add(t, prop.Name, attrs)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Because `xsd.exe` produces partial classes you can add this `EmitDefaultValuesAttribute` in seperate a file:

```
<EmitDefaultValuesAttribute()>
Public MyClass
    Public Property SubClass() As MySubClass
End Class

<EmitDefaultValuesAttribute()>
Public MySubClass
End Class
```

Usage is as follows:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyClass), EmitDefaultValuesAttribute.GetOverrides(GetType(MyClass).Assembly))
```

Comment: Sounds like dynamic attribute manipulation for given object during serialization. It is not very clear for me how it works and I don't understand 100% `vb.net` syntax either, so can't figure out how to *hide* `DefaultValue` from your code (but I guess simply not adding it somewhere or replace with *dummy* attribute). Still worth upvoting, thanks!